# routes/web route me to another route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

My web doesn't seem to be directing to the correct page.

Here is my blade

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-lg-12 d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
        <h2>Informations</h2>
        <a href="{{ route('add-new-information') }}" class="btn text-success">
            <i class="fas fa-plus-circle fa-2x"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center mt-5" style="max-height: 500px !important; overflow-y: scroll">
        @foreach ($informations as $info)
            <div class="card col-sm-11 p-0 mb-4 clickable-item" onclick='window.location = "{{ route('admin-informations', ['id' => $info->id]) }}"'>
                ...
            </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my routes/web

```
Auth::routes();

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth'], 'prefix' => '/',], function () {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return redirect('/home');
    });

    Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function() {
        Route::get('/informations', [App\Http\Controllers\InformationController::class, 'index'])->name('informations');
        Route::get('/informations/{id}', [App\Http\Controllers\InformationController::class, 'indexAdminInfo'])->name('admin-informations');
        Route::get('/informations/add-new-information', [App\Http\Controllers\InformationController::class, 'add'])->name('add-new-information');
    });

});
```

and here is my controller

```
    public function indexAdminInfo($id){
        $information = Information::find($id);
        // $comments = Comment::where('information_id', $id)->orderByDesc('created_at')->get();
        $ack_count = Acknowledge::where('information_id', $id)->count();
        $user_ack = Acknowledge::where([
            ['information_id', '=', $id],
            ['user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id],
        ])->first();
        $ack = 'FALSE';
        
        if($user_ack != null){
            $ack = 'TRUE';
        }

        return view('adminviews/infoadmin', compact('information', 'ack_count', 'ack', 'user_ack'));
    }

    public function add(){
        return view('adminviews/addinfo');
    }
```

For some reason, when I click the a tag with the href `{{ route('add-new-information') }}` to go to the add page `'adminviews/addinfo'`,

instead the page will go to the `'adminviews/infoadmin' page`, which will cause an error, because no parameters are being sent.

I tried checking the code, but it looks correct to me. Can anybody find an error on this?

Comment: Have you tried changing your link to `/admin/informations/add-new-information`? What happens when you click on that?

Comment: I can see if you click ` {{ route('add-new-information') }}` it will appear  `adminviews/addinfo`. There is no issues about it

Comment: @fufubrocat Having the href as /admin/informations/add-new-information still tries to go to the 'adminviews/infoadmin' blade.

Comment: @A.ANoman. Yes, it should go to the addinfo blade, but that is not the case. I tried reviewing it and passing a php artisan optimize in the terminal, and yet I still get directed to the infoadmin blade.

Comment: @Tim Sobrecarey can you try disabling `Route::get('/informations/add-new-information', [App\Http\Controllers\InformationController::class, 'add'])->name('add-new-information');` first and use `Route::get('/admin/informations/add-new-information', 'InformationController@add'):` instead?

Comment: @fufubrocat It still gave me the same thing. It's ok, I just overhauled the entire function, route, blade, also renaming them. It seems to work with this. I'm not sure what the cause is though. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is with your routes:
these two routes are ambiguous:

```
Route::get('/informations/{id}');
Route::get('/informations/add-new-information');
```

just think of below scenario:

router wants to route, this url : `/information/add-new-information`

router will hit the first defined route, because it is compatible with the definition (`'/informations/{id}'`)

> Note :`{id}` is a variable and can be any string

so it will go with this.

### Solution

write the more restricted route first,

and more general route later:

```php
Route::get('/informations/add-new-information');
Route::get('/informations/{id}');
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I will also try this method.